# GSM DATA INTERCHANGE

Tags: gsm, at-command, ussd

I was wondering if it is possible to send via GSM protocol and appropriate AT commands, few data through a simple GSM call (witout using data traffic).
For example my system is a PIC + GSM Module and it monitors and processes a string of data. 
When the user wishes, he makes a voice call in order to interacts with the GSM module via DTMF commands  for example via an APP. 
My dubt is if the GSM module is able to send the data to thesmartphone in order to monitor the status of the system. The module is a Quectel M95.
During some investigation, I saw that the module can send USSD codes but I don't know if it's possible to customize the USSD and read it from the smartphone as I wish. 
Or maybe is it possible to use the FAX for data exchange?

Thanks everybody in advance

Marco

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of alternatives if you want to avoid using data traffic. But they all require either a connection to a service that is capable of receiving SMS's for example Twilio. Or you can of course have a GSM Module connected to your server which could do the receiving.

You could then send your data and requests for data within an standard SMS body. Or alternatively you could send binary SMS's where you are not limited to the 7 bit character set.

USSD would only work if you have a USSD service provider (I think Twilio has this now). Because the USSD service must initiate a USSD session for your target GSM Module to respond to. USSD code sending for GSM Modules is operator specific and therefore you are limited to what they have implemented (usually for prepaid users and the topping up of accounts).